# getting old values of updated domain properties in grails

Tags: events, grails, dns, beforeupdate

I am trying to implement the beforUpdate event in grails domain classes I need to audit log both the old and new values of the Domains attributes. I see that we can use the `isDirty` check or use `Domain.dirtyPropertyNames` which return list of properties which are dirty in the domain. and `getPersistentValue` gets the old value in the table so I can have both values..

For implementing this I will be using the beforUpdate event in the domain class and call a logging service from there, passing it the id of the User domain. now using this ID I can get user Instance in Service and then check if any fields are dirty using the above specified method? or do I need to log the Audit when I am actually doing the Update in the UserController's update def?

Which is the better approach?

I want to confirm if this the right approach..
Also what other things I need to take care for, Like: 
1) if the attributes are domain object references and not simple types. 
2) any other things I need to take care like not flushing out the hibernate session, thinking of implementing this in call to service from the domain class.
Regards,
Priyank

Edit: I tried this in the beforeUpdate event in User domain that I want to Audit log for Update activity..

```
def beforeUpdate = {
GraauditService service = AH.getApplication().getMainContext().getBean(''graauditService)
        service.saveUserUpdateEntry(this.id); // id property of User domain...
}
```

In the method in Service I do:

```
def saveUserUpdateEntry(Long id){
    User grauser = User.get(id);
    println ("user="+ grauser)
    println "Dirty Properties -: ${grauser.dirtyPropertyNames}"
    println "Changed value for firstName =  -: ${ grauser.firstName}"
    println "Database value for firstName =  -: ${ grauser.getPersistentValue('firstName')}"

    }
```

I try to do the update from the UI for email, firstname, lastname and get the following on console:

```
user=com.gra.register.User : 1
Dirty Properties -: [eMail, firstName, lastName]
Changed value for firstName =  -: sefser
Database value for firstName =  -: administer

user=com.gra.register.User : 1
Dirty Properties -: []
Changed value for firstName =  -: sefser
Database value for firstName =  -: sefser
possible nonthreadsafe access to session
```

I am not able to know: 
1) Why am I getting 2 sets ... is the event called twice once before commit and once after commit...??
2) how to remove or handle the Hibernate exception (tried to use withNew session in the function but no difference

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: There are plenty of ways you could do this pri_dev, and the best approach probably depends on what the business requirements are. Do you want every change to the User logged, or only the properties that changed? How often do expect this object to update? Are you planning to persist these changes to a database, something mapped by GORM, a log file..?

Comment: Yes, I want to add it to AuditLog Domain in the database, I tried to do simple call to service from beforeUpdate and its throwing hibernate exception. I have added the edit section

Comment: One more really important question I have is, If I updated 2-3 attributes in the domain and call save() the beforUpdate event is called, but is the Save event also called? since both create and update are calls to domain.save() I want to know if Hibernate is smart enough to fire different event based on new Creation and Update of existing Domain..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using GORM event handlers for audit logging, use [audit logging plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging). This will take away a lot of pain of yours.

Hope this helps.

or

If You want much finer control over what you are doing you should consider using a subclass of Hibernate's EmptyInterceptor. This will serve tow purposes for you

1. Will give you much finer control over what and how you are doing the audit logging
2. Will place all your logic for audit logging at one place, which will help you maintaining your code.

[Click here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) to see the API for EmptyInterceptor.

> **Note**: Hibernate does not ship any implementation in this class and also don't provide any subclass of this which might provide you the default behavior. So you will have to write a custom implementation.

Comment: We tried that, but for logging onLoad events (like XYZ logged on at a time..) its difficult to use the same domain they have... And we dont wont to maintain 2 tables so just panning to implement all without the plugin, also I dont know how to get like the ID of the object which is getting deleted...when using the plugin..

Comment: I dont know this plugin but I assume the old ID is in the `oldmap`.